# What is the use of CreateProcess() API function?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, win32-process

I'm new to Windows system programming and I'm trying to learn the `CreateProcess()` function.

I know that it's possible to run a new process, for instance, `notepad.exe` or `cmd.exe` by the calling program by giving the name (`notepad` or `cmd.exe`) as parameter to the  `CreateProcess()` function in the calling program.

What is the use of doing that, and could you explain any real world application for that?

Can I use this create process function to clone itself and do something in parallel?

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. If you don't know what real use of starting processes in Windows (which is the purpose of [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ) you may want to use Windows a bit first and pay attention to what heppens when you start some applications... If you trying to port `fork` - check out [Porting tfrom UNIX to Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx) article... Or maybe something else altogether?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the use of doing that, and could you explain any real world application for that?

`CreateProcess` is the way to create new processes on Windows. Obvious examples of its use would be for the shell to start new applications. Or for the command line interpreter to execute external commands.

> Can I use this create process function to clone itself and do something in parallel?

No. Windows processes don't use the *nix fork idiom. There is no analogue in Windows to forking.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use this create process function to clone itself and do something in parallel?

Not so much a clone, no.  But the calling app can spawn a separate instance of itself, by specify its own filename, possibly with command-line parameter(s) to tell the spawned process what to do.  So in that regard, yes, you can have multiple instances of your app running in parallel.